# Error 404 - Magento site homepage not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I'm fairy new to Magento and have limited knowledge in JavaScript, but recently the company I work for has faced an issue with our website. The website is loading with 2 errors displayed in the JavaScript console which are...

```
GET http://________.com/js/qu/slider.js 

Uncaught TypeError: Ajax.Autocompleter is not a constructorVarien.searchForm.initAutocomplete @ VM204 js.js:342(anonymous function) @ (index):139
VM204 js.js:342
```

Because of this, part of the homepage is not loading correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Java" is to "JavaScript" what "Ham" is to "Hamster". They're not the same by a large margin.

Comment: Maybe some JS classes are not instantiating.

Comment: @KingshuckDeb wat would I need to do? I apologise for my limited knowledge in all of this...